# Possible to use NFC for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, nfc

I know that iPads do not have the ability to read NFC tags, unless paired with an iPhone.  However, I know there are payment systems that use an iPad to scan NFC credit cards, so I am hopeful there is some sort of hardware I can plug or connect to an iPad and allow reading of NFC ids.

Is anyone aware of how to do this?

Comment: It is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to seek recommendations for third-party tools, or the like (as it just leads to spam/advertising). But a quick web search for “ipad nfc external” (or permutations thereof) will produce a number of hits. Solutions range from payment-system-specific hardware to more generic NFC reader/writers. But, alas, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you @Rob - I hadn't thought of it that way - I certainly don't want to promote more spam!

Thank you also for the google search term, I hadn't tried that permutation yet.